# Passing Django Template Variables to Javascript... securely

Tags: javascript, django

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = "{{Django_Variable}}"
</script>
```

I get this idea.

But what if these Django Template variables contain sensitive information? I have written a Javascript application that needs to receive data from Django, but my current implementation shamelessly displays all the details in developer mode.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        MyApp.init(
            userid: 46,
            hasPermission: False,
            secretData: "Not anymore",
            ...
        );
    });
</script>
```

The data I'm trying to pass in are not as sensitive as credit card or password information, but sensitive enough that I need to hide it. I have considered firing AJAX GET after the page loads, but that just adds extra overhead.

How do I pass in Django Template variables to my Javascript without showing it in HTML?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no real differences when it comes to this whether it be django or any other framework . The problem inherently has to do with the fact that javascript is client side technology. 
However yes ajax request is one possible . Others can be minifying/encrypting etc ... Anything that you would use for any other framework. I would say you should read these answers to get a better picture:

[Secure data in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374115/secure-data-in-javascript)